# JQuery : How to acess form elements after load

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, load

I've load form as this :

```
$('#content').load('contacts/contact.php #content' );
```

And my form html is :

```
<div id="content">
<div class="post">
    <h1 class="title">Nous contacter</h1>

    <div class="entry">

        <div id='form_wrap'>

            <form method="post" name="contactForm" id="contactForm">
                <p>hi,</p>
                <label for="sujet">Sujet: </label>
                <input type="text" name="sujet" value="" id="sujet" class="validate[required,custom[chaine]] text-input" data-prompt-position="topLeft:10"/>
                <label for="message">Message : </label>
                <textarea  name="message" value="Votre Message" id="message" class="validate[required] text-input" data-prompt-position="topLeft:20"></textarea>
                <p></p> 
                <label for="name">Nom: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="name" class="validate[required,custom[chaine]] text-input" data-prompt-position="topLeft:10"/>
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input" data-prompt-position="topLeft:10"/>
                <input type="submit" name ="env" id ="env" value="Envoyer" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

I want to get values of elements in forms after submit, i try to do :

```
$("#sujet").val()
```

but it doesn't work !!!

how to get them (after submit) ?

thank's

Comment: We need to see the script as well...

Comment: the script is :

$("#contactForm").submit( function() { 
 $.ajax({ 
 type: "POST",
  url: "actionContact.php",
data: "sujet="+$("#sujet").val()+"&nom="+$("#name").val()+"&email="+$("#email").val()+"&message="+$('textarea[id="message"]').val() ,       success: function(msg){ 
if(msg==1) 
 {
      $("div.post").html("<span id=\"confirmMsg\">Vous &ecirc;tes maintenant connect&eacute;.</span>");    
}
else
{
alert('erreurs');
$("div.post").html("Erreur lors de la connexion");
 }
 }
});
return false; 
});

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.get()` function:

```
$.get('contacts/contact.php #content', function(data) {
  console.log($(data, "#sujet").val());
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

you could use `serialize()` or `serializeArray()` for setting the data:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "actionContact.php", 
    data: $(this).serializeArray()
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Comment: can i get values before ajax calls ?